# How often should I change oil in the CVT transmission

Tags: mazda, cvt-transmission

What is the recommended interval for the oil change in the CVT transmission for Mazda 2 2007, Chassis DE3FS

**EDIT**

The reason why I'm asking this questions is I don't have the user manual and local dealerships are not willing to help as my car is Japanise import and Mazda 2 for the local market (New Zealand) comes with 'normal' AT.

Answer (score 2):

Considering how finicky CVT's can be, and how expensive they are to replaced, I would follow the manufacturer recommended service intervals and fluid types. From what I've read, most manufacturers recommend changing CVT fluid every 30k miles or 24 months. You should double check with your owners manual or dealership service department for the correct fluid type and service interval.

I would also recommend having it done at an independent mechanic who is experience with CVT transmissions, rather than the dealership (expensive) or a quick-lube type shop (incompetent, in my experience).

EDIT:

The amount of time I have spent searching for this information would be described by the guy that signs by paychecks as "clear out your desk, and don't bother coming in on Monday."

I was able to find *some* information by searching for the Mazda Demio, which is the 2's JDM (Japanese Domestic Market) model name. Even then, I was only able to find the recommended fluid is [CVTF 3320](http://content.valvoline.com/pdf/cvt_fluid.pdf), which is produced my multiple companies (Mobil 1, Valvoline, etc).

Considering that the dealership is not willing to help, I would call the Mazda corporate office, who should be able to look it up, or connect you with someone who will be able to answer your question.

Good Luck!

Comment: In general, yes I should check the manual. In my question, I specifically provided model, year, and chassis number because I don't have the manual. Dealerships are not willing to help as  my car is Japanise import and the Mazda 2 for the local market comes with a normal AT transmission.

Comment: @MikhailChibel Ahh, makes sense, I specifically left out the service interval for the car listed, as I was unable to find any specific info! You may want to add those details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same vehicle in NZ (Demio Jap import).... the only people I found to assist were Kaspa Transmissions in Silverdale, Auckland; no one else could seem to be able find the correct fluid. I've had them flush and change the oil/fluid twice, once when I first bought it and again after around 50,000kms.  I don't know if this is the correct interval or not but with it being a CVT it seemed reasonable.  Hope this helps.